# get.RGB возвращает int, как определить цвет?

Tags: java

```
BufferedImage myBufferedImage = myRobot.createScreenCapture(wholeScreenRectangle);
if(myBufferedImage.getRGB(x, y) == -2374261 && myBufferedImage.getRGB(x+791, y+545) == -4678566)
{
 //my implementation here
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, get.RGB, как я понял возвращает int-овское значение, заглянув в документацию я увидел что оно возвращается в формате n

> the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB)

Но я не понял, как преобразовывать в эту модель. Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модель `TYPE_INT_ARGB` обозначает, что в `int` (который, как известно 4 байта) упакованы компоненты цвета в следующем порядке:

- биты 31-24 - **A**lpha - альфа-канал
- биты 23-16 - **R**ed - красный канал
- биты 15-8 - **G**reen - зеленый канал
- биты 7-0 - **B**lue - синий канал

Разбить `int` на байты не составит труда:

```
int argb = myBufferedImage.getRGB(x, y); 
int alpha = (argb >> 24) & 0xff;
int red = (argb >> 16) & 0xff;
int green = (argb >>  8) & 0xff;
int blue = (argb ) & 0xff;
```

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, но что такое альфа-канал? и как мне перевести в модель, например, такой цвет:
R 94 G 34 B 52 или #5F2234 (тот же цвет, но в HEX)?

Comment: Альфа-канал - это уровень прозрачности

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov, `#5F2234` соответственно будет `int argb = 0xFF5F2234` (`FF` в альфа-канале для полной непрозрачности).

Comment: Те если нам getRGB вернул int-ое значение -1250856, достаточно его перевести в hex и это и будет наш цвет? (за исключением первых двух FF)

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov, да, смотрите пример кода в ответе.